# Like Statement is not working for me in sequelize

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js, sql-like

### What are you doing?

```js
/* Code for Pagination */
    let limit = 4;   // number of records per page
    let offset = 0;
    let countallCompanies = 1000; 
    let page = req.body.page;      // 1 by default page number
    let order_by = req.body.order_by;  // id by default
    let order_by_ASC_DESC = req.body.order_by_ASC_DESC; // ASC by default
    let pages = Math.ceil(countallCompanies.count / limit);
    offset = limit * (page - 1); 
    /* End code for Pagination */
[err, companies] = await to(Company.findAll({ 
        where: { company_name: { like: '%'+ req.body.q +'%' } },
        limit: limit,
        offset: offset,
        order: [[order_by, order_by_ASC_DESC]]        
    }));
```

### What do you expect to happen?

I expect sequelize to generate this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `Companies` AS `Company` WHERE company_name LIKE '%aa%' ORDER BY `Company`.`id` ASC LIMIT 0, 4
```

### What is actually happening?

Instead it generates this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `Companies` AS `Company` ORDER BY `Company`.`id` ASC LIMIT 0, 4
```

The `WHERE` condition is not added to my query even though the other clauses are like `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT`, etc. I have tried using both `like` and `$like`, but neither worked.  If I add `where: { id: 53 }` then the `WHERE` clause does appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `const Op = Sequelize.Op;` at start of file.

There are two ways to use like. `$like: [Op.like]`.

Also try with hard coded value to see if your data is fine.